# Match values between Excel worksheets and copy row to another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 3 worksheets within my Excel file. Missing (25,000 rows), Valid (18,000 rows), and Matched (blank).

I need to compare the values in column D of Missing and Valid and copy all the rows of all the matches to the Matched sheet.

If I can somehow do a wildcard search with this that would be nice too, for example a way for ABBOTT LABORATORIES to match ABBOTT LAB. If that isn't possible, then if there is a way to highlight the rows that have been matched so I can manually find the wildcard matches would be very appreciated.

This is what I have tried, I found it via Google, but I don't fully understand the code. It ran for a few minutes without errors, but no data was pulled:

```
Sub CopyRows() 
Dim cell As Range 
Dim found As Range 
Dim dcol 
Dim bcol 
Dim totalrows1 As Long 
Dim totalrows2 As Long 

totalrows1 = Sheets("Valid").UsedRange.Rows.Count 
bcol = "$D$2:$D$" & totalrows1 
totalrows2 = Sheets("Missing").UsedRange.Rows.Count 
dcol = "$D$2:$D$" & totalrows2 
For Each cell In Sheets("Valid").Range(bcol) 
    If Not Sheets("Missing").Range(dcol).Find(What:=cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then 
        Set found = Sheets("Missing").Range(dcol).Find(What:=cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) 
        If found.Offset(0, -3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value And found.Offset(0, -2).Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value Then 
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = found.Offset(0, -1).Value 
        End If 
    End If 
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all to get this work? You will find more help if you show your effort, versus just telling us what you need. See www.stackoverflow.com/faq for more information.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman actually for me it doesnt make a difference at all whether the OP tried or not

Comment: I added the script that I tried.

Comment: You can use wild cards in `Filter` and `Find` excel functions. Use `*` to determine what part of the wild card you want to represent. Eg. `"Br*"` will look for everything starting with Br while `"*br*"` will look for everything containing br.

What are you trying to achieve with the `If found.offset` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Won't manage approximate matches but otherwise: Amalgamate Missing and Valid in Matched, sort on `ColumnD` then apply a highlight with conditional formatting to identify adjacent matching ‘D’ values. Filter and delete those not highlighted. Review of [SU486330](https://superuser.com/questions/486330/formula-to-compare-the-source-and-the-target-based-on-id/486380#486380) may help.